android autocomplete textbox with single checkbox selection & event handler fire
I am implementing autocomplete textbox with checkbox selection event handler but event handler not working when we implement check changed event within custom adapter then its call multiple time at single tap. Please help.
try many approach like change event handler, calling scope but not getting success.

How are we supposed,to help?  You have not provided any code illustrating what you are doing
